# Python 3.something. Arithmetic function with remainder

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do an arithmetic operation where I get an input from user and calculate with their input. I know how to do division with their input but I also want to obtain the remainder from that division for further use. How do I do that?

Comment: So you didn't know what a modulo is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
remainder = nominator % denominator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("enter number "))
b=int(input("enter number "))
c=a/b
remainder=a%b
```

`a` and `b` are the values that we are taking from user, `c` is quotient and remainder contain the remainder. You should take a look at the [modulus (%) operator docs for python](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html)